# Can't populate a property in model in ngSelect

Tags: angularjs, select

Code for creating Dropdown with AngularJs.

```
<select ng-model="ctrl.editLayout" ng-options="layout.text for layout in ctrl.editLayouts"></select>
```

JS Code

```
$scope.ctrl = {"editLayout": "1", "editLayouts": [{ "id": "1", "text": "1 column" }, { "id": "2", "text": "2 column" }]}
```

When user selects an item(e.g. say "1 column"), whole objects gets populated in editLayout i.e.

```
editLayout = { "id": "1", "text": "1 column" }
```

Instead, I want

```
editLayout = 1
```

How can I accomplish it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
<select ng-model="ctrl.editLayout" ng-options="layout.id as layout.text for layout in ctrl.editLayouts"></select>
```

The key part being the "layout.id as...

Comment: thanks, that did the magic... its not allowing to mark you comment as answer, asking me to wait... will do in some time